# How to Delete XML Node?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have created methods for selecting and removing nodes from XML. My code runs but XML node is not removed.

I do not know where the code is wrong please help me for this problem:

```
public XmlNodeList getXmlNodeList(string XmlNodeName)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(_connection);
    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlNodeName);
    return elemList;
}

public void deleteXmlNode(string XmlNodeName, string XmlNodeValue)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(_connection);
    XmlNodeList xnode = getXmlNodeList(XmlNodeName);

    foreach (XmlNode item in xnode)
    {
        if (item.InnerText == XmlNodeValue)
        {
            item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item);
            break;
        }
    }
    xdoc.Save(_connection);
}
```

My XML code:

```
<AriaGostarInformation>
  <MenuInformation>
    <MenuNames>
      one
    </MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="1">two</MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="2">three</MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="3">four</MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="4">five</MenuNames>
    <MenuNames Name="5">six</MenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="1">
      fgfgfgfgs
    </SubMenuNames>
    <SubMenuNames parentName="3">
    </SubMenuNames>
  </MenuInformation>
  <SliderInformation>
  </SliderInformation>
  <LasProductInformation>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ImageAddress alt="">../Static/Css/Images/c.jpg</ImageAddress>
      <Subject>bere</Subject>
      <Description>nare</Description>
    </Product>
  </LasProductInformation>
</AriaGostarInformation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hurting your performance by loading two separate `XmlDocument` objects to look up the nodes of your xmltree.  However, it does not look like you have anything actually wrong.  You may not be passing valid parameters.  Have you attempted to add in any tracing to see what values are being submitted to the methods?  Also just a suggestion that these two methods can be combined into a very short method using Linq-to-Xml using the following code for your delete node method.  The below can delete all matching nodes:

```
public void deleteXmlNode(string xmlNodeName, string xmlNodeValue)
{
     XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(_connection);
     var xNodeList = xDoc.Descendants(xmlNodeName).Where(n => n.Value == xmlNodeValue);
     xNodeList.Remove();
}
```

SOURCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx